# Wordpress 301 redirect error while plugin uninstalled

Tags: wordpress

On my wordpress website, I used wp-301-redirect plugin to redirect the www to non-www. However, I uninstalled the plugin.

When I try to access to the www website multiple time, an error is thrown :

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in /home/********/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-301-redirects/wp-simple-301-redirects.php on line 220
```

But these files doesn't exist anymore.

Things done :

- I emptied the cache multiples times, manually and wp plugin.
- The server has been rebooted since the plugin uninstall.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server after you have uninstalled the plugin, assuming you have access?

Comment: Are you completely sure that those files don't exist anymore? Watch out, remotely deleting files using any kind of GUI sometimes may  become a PITA.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar Well. I connected via ssh to the server, these files aren't there... The entire 301 redirect directory is deleted

Comment: @SantanuDey Nop, and can't reboot it untin 01AM (GMT 00.00), too many visitors atm.

Comment: This question may sound stupid. Are you sure you're in the right wordpress directory?

Comment: It's a good thing that you check, but yes I'm sure... I'm not the only one on this issue, and we're all sure that these files don't exists anymore as we checked. We think that it's a cache problem, but we flushed it multiple times.

Comment: Are you using any cache service. If so, try to clean you cache.

Comment: Edited to provide more informations